# Error while using update_function_code in aws lambda with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda

The following is my code to update lambda function

```
 self.client1.update_function_code(
            FunctionName='testdeploy',
            ZipFile=base64.b64encode(open("TestZip.zip","rb").read())
        )
```

However it throws me the following error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testBotoLambda.py", line 94, in <module>
    test.update_lambda(os.getcwd()+"lambda")
  File "testBotoLambda.py", line 83, in update_lambda
    ZipFile=base64.b64encode(open("TestZip.zip","rb").read())
  File "/home/surabhi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 310, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/surabhi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 599, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (400) when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation:
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error message? It seems to be cut off.

Comment: @peter edited the code and error, thanks.

Comment: Hey your error is still cutting off. We need to see what's after the "when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation:" to be able to do anything with this

Comment: That's the entire error @ChrisWhite ya there is nothing after the colon, it is weird.

Comment: Does your lambda function have a role attached that allows it access to the Lambda service? I know it sounds a bit weird since the lambda function is in the Lambda service, but running a function is different permissions wise than have that function update parts of the lambda service itself.

Comment: 400 response from UpdateFunctionCode means CodeStorageExceededException or InvalidParameterValueException, according to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateFunctionCode.html.

Comment: @jarmod thanks. Does that mean I need to reduce the zip file size? what do you think?

Comment: @ChrisWhite yes, and I tried to pass the lambda arn too it still gave the same error.